# encoding date/time in RFC3999

Tags: ruby

What is the right way to encode date/times in RFC3999? Should I just gsub the colons?

my code:

```
base="https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/candles?instrument="
curr="EUR_USD"
granularity="H1"
#example time: 2014-06-19T15%3A47%3A40Z
startTime=(DateTime.now-5000).to_s #current time -5000 seconds
endTime=DateTime.now.to_s
myurl=base+curr+"&candleFormat=bidask&granularity="+granularity+"&dailyAlignment=0&alignmentTimezone=America%2FNew_York&start="+startTime+"&end="+endTime
puts "---string:"
puts myurl
puts "---encoded:"
puts URI::encode(myurl)
puts "---correct example:"
puts "https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/candles?instrument=EUR_USD&start=2014-06-19T15%3A47%3A40Z&end=2014-06-19T15%3A47%3A50Z"
```

output (my goal is to have the times show up like the final line below):

```
---string:
https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/candles?instrument=EUR_USD&candleFormat=bidask&granularity=H1&dailyAlignment=0&alignmentTimezone=America%2FNew_York&start=2002-09-26T23:09:07-04:00&end=2016-06-04T23:09:07-04:00
---encoded:
https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/candles?instrument=EUR_USD&candleFormat=bidask&granularity=H1&dailyAlignment=0&alignmentTimezone=America%252FNew_York&start=2002-09-26T23:09:07-04:00&end=2016-06-04T23:09:07-04:00
---correct example:
https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/candles?instrument=EUR_USD&start=2014-06-19T15%3A47%3A40Z&end=2014-06-19T15%3A47%3A50Z
```

The code from the answer below:

```
base="https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/candles?instrument="
curr="EUR_USD"
granularity="H1"
#DID NOT WORK
startTime="2014-06-19T15%3A47%3A40Z" #2014-06-19T15%3A47%3A40Z
endTime=CGI.escape(DateTime.now.to_s) #2016-06-05T04%3A26%3A30-04%3A00
#WORKS
#startTime="2014-06-19T15%3A47%3A40Z"
#endTime="2014-06-19T15%3A47%3A50Z"
puts startTime
puts endTime
myurl = "#{ base }#{ curr }&candleFormat=bidask&granularity=#{ granularity }&dailyAlignment=0&alignmentTimezone=America%2FNew_York&start=#{ startTime }&end=#{ endTime }"
puts myurl
response =HTTParty.get(myurl)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try doing it like so which will escape each date in a safe way

```
require 'cgi'
require 'date'
require 'uri'

base="https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/candles?instrument="
curr="EUR_USD"
granularity="H1"

startTime=CGI.escape((DateTime.now-5000).to_s)
endTime=CGI.escape(DateTime.now.to_s)
myurl = "#{ base }#{ curr }&candleFormat=bidask&granularity=#{ granularity }&dailyAlignment=0&alignmentTimezone=America%2FNew_York&start=#{ startTime }&end=#{ endTime }"
puts "---encoded:"
puts myurl
```

Which yields this

```
https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/candles?instrument=EUR_USD&candleFormat=bidask&granularity=H1&dailyAlignment=0&alignmentTimezone=America%2FNew_York&start=2002-09-26T23%3A55%3A31-04%3A00&end=2016-06-04T23%3A55%3A31-04%3A00
```

Which, when a url decoder runs across one of the dates will decode back into

```
2016-06-04T23:55:31-04:00
```

Comment: I tried your code and updated my post. Any idea why that didnt work? The API request failed, but it worked perfectly when I used the string dates (commented out above)

Comment: My code failed because of an API error, your code works perfectly